# Multiple Options/MYSQL Records to input box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I wondered if anyone would be able to help me with this as I just can't for the life of me, get it to work.

any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```js
$('#options').change(function () {
var optionname=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-value');
var optionprice=$(this).find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
$('#optionname').val(optionname);
$('#optionprice').val(optionprice);
});
```

```html
<select name="options[]" id="options" class="form-control" required>
 <option value="">Select Option</option>
 <?php
 $results99 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM productoptions WHERE productid = '$prod_id' AND cat = 1");
 while($rows99 = $results99->fetch_assoc()) {
 ?>
 <option data-value="<?php echo $rows99['optionname']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $rows99['price']; ?>"><?php echo ucwords(strtolower($rows99['optionname'])); ?> (+<?php echo $rows99['price']; ?>)</option>
 <?php
 //$results99->free();
 }
 ?>
 </select>
 <?php } ?>
<input type="text" name="optionname" id="optionname" />
<input type="text" name="optionprice" id="optionprice" />
```

I just can't get it to work properly

Comment: What exactly is not working? `PHP` rendering? 'jQuery' filling `input`? Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cxgg21md/ and let me know what it should do beside it does now.

Comment: It works for the first record of the list of mysql records but doesn't for the rest

Comment: I still do not get it. If you have one `select` (with 2 `options`) and two `inputs`, what should happen when you choose some of the `options`?

Comment: option values should populate the input boxes, but it is populating the first input box in the first record instead of say the 15th record

Comment: Let's have a quick chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89172/multiple-options-mysql-records-to-input-box

Comment: Now it is :) Please join

Comment: Still giving me the same, reputation 20 or more

Comment: How about this one: https://tlk.io/so-chat